# Truncate 64Bit Integer to 32Bit and simulate value

Tags: php, type-conversion, integer, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I'm trying to write an algorithm to convert a 64Bit integer to 32Bit via truncation, and return a value accurately representing a 32Bit value. The obvious problem is that integers in PHP are only 64Bit (barring 32Bit systems).

I first tried the following:

```
$x = $v & 0xFFFFFFFF
```

So if `$v = PHP_INT_MAX`, `$x` is `4294967295`, when really I want `-1`. I know the reason for this is that when represented as a 64Bit integer, PHP prepends the zeros to the last 32 bits, and thats why I get a positive number.

My solution so far is this:

```
function convert64BitTo32Bit(int $v): int
{
    $v &= 0xFFFFFFFF;

    if ($v & 0x80000000) {
        return $v | 0xFFFFFFFF00000000;
    }

    return $v;
}
```

And I'm pretty sure its right. The problem I have with this is that it requires that `if` statement to inspect whether the truncated number is negative. I was really hoping for a bitwise only solution. It may not be possible, but I thought I'd ask.

EDIT:

The problem can be simplified to just part of the solution. i.e. if the first bit is `1`, make all bits `1`, if first bit is `0` make all bits `0`.

```
# example assumes input is the LSBs of an 8Bit integer.
# scale for 64Bit and the same solution should work.

op(1010) = 1111
op(0101) = 0000

op(0000) = 0000
op(1000) = 1111
op(0001) = 0000
```

I would be able to use the LSBs to derive this value, then mask it onto the MSBs of the 64Bit integer. This is what I'm trying to figure out now, though I'm trying to avoid creating a monster equation.

Comment: Have you considered using the GMP extension? This is able to handle big numbers. To be able to handle them your input and output them on strings.

Comment: Can you please specify what do you mean when say "representing a 32Bit value"?

Comment: My goal is to simulate an overflow. To this end I've been playing with C#.Net trying to do the exact same thing using only `long`, but I can't do it there either using only bitwise operators.

Answer (score 2):

There's probably a more elegant/efficient way using bitwise operations, but you can also force the conversion with `pack()` and `unpack()`. Eg: Pack as unsigned, unpack as signed.

```
function overflow32($in) {
    return unpack('l', pack('i', $in & 0xFFFFFFFF))[1];
}

var_dump( overflow32(pow(2,33)-1) ); // int(-1)
```

I'm curious what you're applying this to, because I had to break a hash function with this same thing some years ago when I moved an app from a 32 bit machine to a 64 bit machine, but I can't remember what it was.

**Edit:** Wow for some reason I remembered [Two's Complement](https://www.cs.cornell.edu/~tomf/notes/cps104/twoscomp.html) being hard. Literally just invert and add one.

```
function overflow32($in) {
    if( $in & 0x80000000 ) {
        return ( ( ~$in & 0xFFFFFFFF) + 1 ) * -1;
    } else {
        return $in & 0xFFFFFFFF;
    }
}

var_dump( kludge32(pow(2,33)-1) );
```

**Edit 2:** I saw that you want to extend this to arbitrary bit lengths, in which case you just need to calculate the masks instead of explicitly setting them:

```
function overflow_bits($in, $bits=32) {
    $sign_mask = 1 << $bits-1;
    $clamp_mask = ($sign_mask << 1) - 1;

    var_dump(
        decbin($in),
        decbin($sign_mask),
        decbin($clamp_mask)
    );

    if( $in & $sign_mask ) {
        return ( ( ~$in & $clamp_mask) + 1 ) * -1;
    } else {
        return $in & $clamp_mask;
    }
}

var_dump(
    overflow_bits(pow(2, 31), 32),
    overflow_bits(pow(2, 15), 16),
    overflow_bits(pow(2, 7), 8)
);
```

I left in the debug `var_dump()`s for output flavor:

```
string(32) "10000000000000000000000000000000"
string(32) "10000000000000000000000000000000"
string(32) "11111111111111111111111111111111"
string(16) "1000000000000000"
string(16) "1000000000000000"
string(16) "1111111111111111"
string(8) "10000000"
string(8) "10000000"
string(8) "11111111"
int(-2147483648)
int(-32768)
int(-128)
```

Comment: Thanks, i am aware of pack and unpack however, and I've used them in the past quite a lot. However I'm trying to avoid using functions or constructs. Also this is solely a hobby piece (for fun), the aim is to cause an overflow as you have done with minimal overhead. If that is the only way however, then it's the only way.

Comment: It's definitely possible. Some bitwise stuff, twos complement, etc. I'd take a crack at it now if I wasn't trying to sleep. Maybe tomorrow. ;)

Comment: I do have an idea how to do it using shift left a copy of the last 32 bits and copy the signing bit onto the first 32 bits of the original, but you can imagine how long that statement would get lol.

Comment: @Flosculus  I've expanded my answer with the Two's Complement method I mentioned.

Comment: I've seen that solution before, and I did try it but didn't get the values I wanted, your first solution of `unpack('l', pack('q', $in))[1]` actual gave the correct result, which as you saw from my own solution, is a real overflow :P But plus one for your help. And to be fair, I cant do with when converting between floats/doubles, so i'll end up having to use pack for that anyway lol.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've cracked it:

```
function overflow32Bit(int $x): int
{
    return ($x & 0xFFFFFFFF) | ((($x & 0xFFFFFFFF) >> 31) * ((2 ** 32) - 1) << 32);
}

var_dump(overflow32Bit(PHP_INT_MAX));     // -1          correct
var_dump(overflow32Bit(PHP_INT_MAX - 1)); // -2          correct
var_dump(overflow32Bit(PHP_INT_MIN));     //  0          correct
var_dump(overflow32Bit((2 ** 31) - 1));   //  2147483647 correct
var_dump(overflow32Bit((2 ** 31)));       // -2147483647 correct
var_dump(overflow32Bit(0xFFFFFFFF));      // -1          correct
var_dump(overflow32Bit(0x7FFFFFFF));      //  2147483647 correct
```

The solution was actually staring me in the face. Get the value of the first bit, then multiply it by the max value of unsigned 32bit integer.

If someone can come up with a better or shorter solution, I'll also accept that.

PS. This is only for 32Bit, i also intend to use this proof for 16Bit and 8Bit.

---

Expanded, `$x` is input, `$z` is output.

```
$x = PHP_INT_MAX;
$y = (2 ** 32) - 1;
$z = ($x & $y) | ((($x & $y) >> 31) * ($y << 32));

var_dump($z);
```

Comment: Haha you're forcing an _actual_ overflow? Bold move. The one note I would offer is that multiplication and exponent operations are computationally expensive compared to bit shifts.

Comment: @Sammitch But I'll wager its faster than an `if` statement? lol, I can't avoid using `if` statements in other places where im using this, so all of this optimization has probably zero benefit. I'm just rather pleased that I can use 1 bit in a multiplication to act as branch.